# Uber H3 Hex - Search database of res 10 indexes for their res 4-9 parents

Tags: h3

I have a large database of location points and their corresponding res 10 hexes.

I need to query this database and identify how many points are in a certain res 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 hex.

Is this possible without adding additional res indexes in the database? Is there a certain format/pattern in the hex naming convention I could use?

Answer (score 3):

All of the children of a res `N` index at res `M` fall within a range, so you can do a range query to find them. This takes a little wrangling, but only to construct the query, not to run it.

To find all the res `10` children of a res `4` index, e.g. `841e001ffffffff`:

- Take `cellToCenterChild('841e001ffffffff')`, which evaluates to `8a1e00000007fff`. This is the bottom of the range.
- The top of the range is a little trickier. We don't currently expose a function for it, but you can construct it by swapping the resolution bits of the parent from `4` to `10`. In hexidecimal, this is conveniently just the second character, so you can swap `4` for `a` yielding `8a1e001ffffffff`. This is not a valid index, but will work for a range query.
- Use a range query to find child indexes:

```
select * from my_data 
  where h3_index between "8a1e00000007fff" and "8a1e001ffffffff";
```

Assuming you have an appropriate index on `h3_index`, this should be fairly fast.